# Quickest way of navigating the code in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

In Xcode 4  is there a way I can set tags on my code to get to frequently accessed methods with minimum clicks.

For example, to get to my viewDidLoad method, can I tag it some way so that I can get to it with some shortcut key or single click?

The only way of navigating the code in Xcode that I'm aware of is using the jump bar at the top. Buy I have so many methods in my class that it takes a while to scroll to the method I want. Is there any other quicker way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you open the jumpbar you can begin typing out the method you want and the method list will begin to get filtered down (and a nifty search box appears inside the opened jumpbar menu to show what you've typed). I'm using Xcode 4.2.1 but I know it was there in 4.2 as well.

Comment: Is there a shortcut to launch the jump bar?

Comment: Not that I've discovered. I found this feature completely on accident one day.

Comment: Its control-6. Now you can jump to any method using the keyboard only.